# Ruby on Rails view not pulling in application.html.erb layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having some issues with a set of views in my rails app. I created ran scaffold to create a posts model, controller and views. They work just fine on their own, but they refuse to pull in the application.html.erb layout.

This is the posts controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @post }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @post, notice: 'Post was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_post
      @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :datecreated, :datemodified, :published, :author)
    end
end
```

Here is one of the views I want to use the application layout:

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Here is the application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Coreyonrails</title>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%= yield %>
    </body>
</html>
```

I saw a post on here regarding the subclass for a controller having < ActionController::Base 
My controller did not have that, and still does not so that didn't help.

Hopefully this isn't a dumb question, I'm still new to rails.

Edited to show file structure.

```
app
  controllers
    application_controller.rb
    pages_controller.rb
    posts_controller.rb
  views
    layouts
      _header.html.erb
      application.html.erb
    pages
      about.html.erb
      contact.html.erb
      home.html.erb
    posts
      _form.html.erb
      _posts.html.erb
      edit.html.erb
      index.html.erb
      new.html.erb
      show.html.erb
```

The rest of the rails generated folders are there as well, I just showed what is relevant to the issue.

The ApplicationController does inherit from ActionController::Base, this is the entire file:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

The pages controller looks similar, and those pages are pulling the application.html.erb correctly without any special work needed.

Here is the repo on github, https://github.com/CoreyT355/website1. Maybe that'll help more.

Comment: where is `application.html.erb` located in the directory structure? Is it happening for all controllers, or just one, or just one action in a controller (if so which action?)

Comment: what's the file structure of your `application.html.erb`? It should be  `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Comment: your application `ApplicationController` should inherit from `ActionController::Base` . It should look like this: `ApplicationController < ActionController::Base`

Comment: edited the post with more info from the comments here

Comment: Is that file supposed to be named `application_html.erb`? Was that a typo in updating the question? Rails normally wants the file to be named `application.html.erb`

Comment: That was a typo on my part, it is application.html.erb in the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things (should be  a comment, but I'll write it here for clarity):

> 1. Check you have `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`
> 2. Check you have `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` inheriting from `ActionController::Base`

When you mention the use of `<%= render "form" %>`, what do you mean? Where is this rendered? If it's rendered from an action, it will be shown on your application layout automatically

Can you post more code for us, specifically `posts_controller`, `application_controller`, `routes` and `application` layout file?

Answer (score 2):

In my case, only one controller's views were not rendering with `layouts/application.html.erb`. Turns out the controller in question was inheriting from `ActionController::Base` instead of `ApplicationController`.

Incorrect:

```
   MyController < ActionController::Base
```

Correct:

```
   MyController < ApplicationController
```